# Why I am getting an "(admin.E003) The value of 'raw_id_fields[N]' must be a ForeignKey or ManyToManyField." error in Django app?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, django-migrations

I want to make a schema migration, just add 1 field to Model and to ModelAdmin.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    some_field = models.ForeignKey(SomeModel)
    my_new_field = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True, choices=[(b'1', b'1'), (b'2', b'2')])

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['some_field', 'my_new_field']
    raw_id_fields = ('some_field', 'my_new_field',)
```

And I got : (admin.E003) The value of 'raw_id_fields[1]' must be a ForeignKey or ManyToManyField.

How can I fix that?
I write an app with Python 2.7, Django 1.8 and PostgreSQL. I also use Docker containers for backend and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields):

> **raw_id_fields** is a list of fields you would like to change into an Input widget for either a ForeignKey or ManyToManyField

`my_new_field` is a `CharField` and its name therefore an invalid element of `raw_id_fields`. This class attribute is meant for **relation fields** where you don't want the overhead of generating the default select dropdown from a queryset but want to use a common input to enter *raw ids*. Just add your field to `fields` instead:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    fields = ['some_field', 'my_new_field']
    raw_id_fields = ['some_field']
```