# @admin.register decorator causing (admin.###) errors in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Using the `@admin.register` decorator is producing (admin.###) errors. I initially suspected it to be relevant to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47406740/why-i-am-getting-an-admin-e003-the-value-of-raw-id-fieldsn-must-be-a-fore) but when fiddling around with this. I found that simply switching to using `admin.site.register` fixes it. When to use `@admin.register` and when to use `admin.site.register` then? I have these models

```
### models.py
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager, 
                    self).get_queryset().filter(
                        status='published'
                    )



class Post(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()       #default manager
    published = PublishedManager()  # custom manager

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
                            unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                              choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                              default='draft')
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail',
                        args=[
                            self.publish.year,
                            self.publish.month,
                            self.publish.day,
                            self.slug
                        ])

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, 
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Comment by {self.name} on {self.post}'
```

and these

```
### admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post, Comment

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Post)
admin.site.register(Comment)



class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title','slug','author','publish','status')
    list_filter = ('status', 'created', 'publish', 'author')
    search_fields = ('title', 'body')
    # prepopulate the slug field with the input of the title field
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
    raw_id_fields = ('author',)
    date_hierarchy = 'publish'
    ordering = ('author','status', 'publish')


class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'email', 'post', 'created', 'active')
    list_filter = ('active', 'created', 'updated')
    search_fields = ('name', 'email', 'body')
```

When I use the decorator `@admin.register`, I get these errors:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/admin/django-samples/blog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/admin/django-samples/blog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/admin/django-samples/blog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in check
    raise SystemCheckError(msg)
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
<class 'blog.admin.PostAdmin'>: (admin.E002) The value of 'raw_id_fields[0]' refers to 'author', which is not an attribute of 'blog.Comment'.
<class 'blog.admin.PostAdmin'>: (admin.E027) The value of 'prepopulated_fields' refers to 'slug', which is not an attribute of 'blog.Comment'.
<class 'blog.admin.PostAdmin'>: (admin.E030) The value of 'prepopulated_fields["slug"][0]' refers to 'title', which is not an attribute of 'blog.Comment'.
<class 'blog.admin.PostAdmin'>: (admin.E033) The value of 'ordering[0]' refers to 'author', which is not an attribute of 'blog.Comment'.
<class 'blog.admin.PostAdmin'>: (admin.E033) The value of 'ordering[1]' refers to 'status', which is not an attribute of 'blog.Comment'.
<class 'blog.admin.PostAdmin'>: (admin.E033) The value of 'ordering[2]' refers to 'publish', which is not an attribute of 'blog.Comment'.
<class 'blog.admin.PostAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[0]' refers to 'title', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'PostAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'blog.Comment'.
<class 'blog.admin.PostAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[1]' refers to 'slug', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'PostAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'blog.Comment'.
<class 'blog.admin.PostAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[2]' refers to 'author', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'PostAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'blog.Comment'.
<class 'blog.admin.PostAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[3]' refers to 'publish', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'PostAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'blog.Comment'.
<class 'blog.admin.PostAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[4]' refers to 'status', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'PostAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'blog.Comment'.
<class 'blog.admin.PostAdmin'>: (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[0]' refers to 'status', which does not refer to a Field.
<class 'blog.admin.PostAdmin'>: (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[2]' refers to 'publish', which does not refer to a Field.
<class 'blog.admin.PostAdmin'>: (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[3]' refers to 'author', which does not refer to a Field.
<class 'blog.admin.PostAdmin'>: (admin.E127) The value of 'date_hierarchy' refers to 'publish', which does not refer to a Field.
```

Switching to using `admin.site.register` as such

```
admin.site.register(Post)
admin.site.register(Comment)
```

fixes it.

Now I'd like to know what's wrong in using

```
@admin.register(Post)
@admin.register(Comment)
```

Comment: Not exactly. It doesn't really provide any explanation why I should use what for which purpose, and it doesn't confirm if @admin.register(Author) and admin.site.register(Author) are actually interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

1) This is a decorator for registering your ModelAdmin classes

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Author

@admin.register(Author)
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

2) This is second way of registering ModelAdmin class.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Author

class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Author, AuthorAdmin)
```

3)when you are not using ModelAdmin you should register like this

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Author

admin.site.register(Author)
```